# How to update a GTK GUI on file creation?

Tags: c, process, gtk, fork

I am trying to create a simple GTK application. I would like to write things on the GUI as soon as certain files are created by different processes. I guess I cannot do a `while(true)` in the parent process, because that would freeze the GUI. Instead, I am trying to fork, check if files are present and manipulate the GUI, but it does not seem to work, my clumsy code is the following:

```
int check_for_files(){
 FILE *fp;
 int files_set;
 char ch;

 files_set = 0;
 while(!files_set){
  fp = fopen("file", "r");
  if(fp != NULL){
     content_length = 0;
     while(ch=getc(fp) != EOF){
      content_length++;
     }
     fclose(fp);
     files_set = 1;
     return files_set;
  }
  else{
     files_set = 0;
  }
 }
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 // Main function the get the application UI

 GtkWidget *window;
 GdkPixbuf *icon;
 GtkWidget *grid;


 gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
 window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
 gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 500, 300);
 gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 15);
 gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

 int pid = fork();

 if (pid == 0){
  int files_set = check_for_files();
  printf("files outside: %d\n",files_set);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Files are present!");
 }
 else{
  icon = create_pixbuf("net.png");
  gtk_window_set_icon(GTK_WINDOW(window), icon);
 // Get the grid
  get_grid(window);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  g_object_unref(icon);
  gtk_main();
  }
}
```

Comment: You should do all GUI updates in the main thread. If you detect some change in another thread. For this purpose,  `g_idle_add()` is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to perform I/O operations, give a look to [gio](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable), which is integrated to GLib. So you should use a [`GFileMonitor`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFileMonitor.html) which uses [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) to be notified of filesystem changes. The "Description" section of `GFileMonitor` presents the functions to use.